# Toggle display on class not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, class, styles

I had code for toggling the display of a div from none to block, it worked fine, but then I realised need it to be on multiple divs. So, I edited the code to go off a class rather than an id, I got help with the code from this site and everyone was saying how it was working perfectly, but it isn't for me.

Here's the code:

```
function toggleDisplay(class) {

    var display = document.getElementsByClassName(class);

    for(var i = 0; i < display.length; ++i) {

        var style = display[i].style;
        style.display = style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
}

toggleDisplay('display');
```

This is the exact code that I found here, that everyone said was working, with just the class name and such changed. It doesn't work. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You need to set the new styles to the elements.

Comment: Do you have classes called display ? that is what you're sending to the function. Class is a reserved word in js, call it toggleclass or something else in the func argument and the function

Comment: I do have a class called display. I have changed the class to className, still not working.

Comment: Why do you use classes when you say you want to act on DIVs separately, use `id` and `document.getElementById()`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct but you are passing reserved keyword `class` as a param. please change it and it would works

```js
function toggleDisplay(className) {

  var display = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

  for(var i = 0; i < display.length; ++i) {

    var style = display[i].style;
    style.display = style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
}

toggleDisplay('display');
```

```html
<p class="display">A paragraph</p>
```

Comment: I have done so, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Comment: @KevinPearseTohill I enabled a snippet and I see it works as you wanted.

Comment: @KevinPearseTohill BTW, the error is `> SyntaxError: class is a reserved identifier`

Comment: I want to be able to toggle the display of multiple divs separately, not all with one click.

Comment: then, you should have a unique ID for all DIVs..is not?

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out. My old code was fine for what I wanted to do, I just had to change some html. Thanks for the help.